# AVPlayer don't update current time when i change player.rate from 4 to 1

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Im using AVPlayer to play m3u8 stream. Current time is normally updated when i increases rate, but if I set it from 4 to 1 or 2, the current time stops updating. If I set this number again to 3 or 4, it will suddenly update to the actual values.
Swift 3.2, iOS 10.2.

Comment: `rate`  The only supported values are 0.50, 0.67, 0.80, 1.0, 1.25, 1.50, and 2.0. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate

Comment: I was going to say that this should be the answer, but those numbers aren't mentioned at that link.

Comment: Actually its supported if canPlayFastForward is true, but only on iOS 10 and higher.